# How to fix bug where right paddle doesn't work when AI is switched on for left paddle? Pong game in canvs javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a pong game in a canvas and there is a bug where the right paddle's AI or movement keys will not work when the left paddle is set to AI.

Here is the code for the paddle objects update(human movement) and updateAI functions respectively:

```
/////////NEED TO FIX AI SO RIGHT PADDLE MOVEMENT WORKS ALL THE ITME AND AI DOES TOO
    Update: function(modifier) {
        //is game paused?
        //LEFT OR RIGHT PLAYER?
        if (this.side === 'left') {
            if (this.isHuman === true) {
                //is player object within boundaries?
                if (this.y >= 0 && this.y <= (canvas.height - this.height)) {

                    if (65 in keysDown) { // Player holding a its 65keycode or 97ascii
                        this.y -= this.speed * modifier;
                    }

                    if (90 in keysDown) { // Player holding z its 90key or 122ascii
                        this.y += this.speed * modifier;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(this.isHuman === false){this.UpdateAI(modifier);}
        //reset paddle if too high or low
            if (this.y < 0) {this.y = 0;}
            if (this.y + this.height > canvas.height) {this.y = canvas.height - this.height;}
        }
        else if (this.side === 'right') {
            if (this.isHuman === true) {
                //is player object within boundaries?
                if (this.y >= 0 && this.y <= (canvas.height - this.height)) {

                    if (75 in keysDown) { // Player holding k
                        this.y -= this.speed * modifier;
                    }

                    if (77 in keysDown) { // Player holding m
                        this.y += this.speed * modifier;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(this.isHuman === false){this.UpdateAI(modifier);}
        //reset paddle if too high or low
            if (this.y < 0) {this.y = 0;}
            if (this.y + this.height > canvas.height) {this.y = canvas.height - this.height;}
        }
    },
    UpdateAI: function(modifier) {
        //create an AI timer or REACTION TIME
        for (i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++) {
            //FAST REACTION
            //the paddle wants it's center to have an equal y coordinate to the ball's y coordinate
            //if the ball is lower than the paddle       paddle goes lower
            if ((this.y + this.height/2) + this.deadZone < Balls[i].GetY()) {this.y += this.speed * modifier;}
            //if the ball is higher than the paddle       paddle goes higher
            else if ((this.y + this.height/2) - this.deadZone > Balls[i].GetY()) {this.y -= this.speed * modifier;}
        }
    },
    /////////////////FIX AI
```

The pong paddles are in an array of Paddle objects called Paddles.  I call UpdatePaddles in the main loop and then UpdatePaddles runs Paddle[0].Update and then Paddles[1].Update.  If isHuman is set to on Paddle.Update checks for key presses, if isHuman is off then it runs .UpdateAI which updates the position.

Here are the buttons that switch the isHuman variable for the paddles:

```
var SwitchLeftAIOnOff = function() {
    Paddles[0].SetIsHuman(!Paddles[0].GetIsHuman());
    if (Paddles[0].GetIsHuman()) {
        leftAIButton.value = 'Left Player: Human';
    }
    else {leftAIButton.value = 'Left Player: AI';}
};

var SwitchRightAIOnOff = function() {
    Paddles[1].SetIsHuman(!Paddles[1].GetIsHuman());
    if (Paddles[1].GetIsHuman()) {
        rightAIButton.value = 'Right Player: Human';
    }
    else {rightAIButton.value = 'Right Player: AI';}
};
```

The right AI works when the left paddle is set to human and the right paddle movement keys work when the left is human, but if the left is AI then neither works.  Let me know if I need to provide more code.

Comment: I have a good look over the code, and nothing stands out as an issue. Have you tried console.logging "this" in the update function? Are the properties as expected?

Comment: yes i have it printing what the value of the right paddle's isHuman variable, I changed the Update code to first ask if isHuman is true or false, then split it into if it's the left or right paddle.

Comment: OK. Only other suggestions are to add console.log to all blocks of the IF statement and see exactly where the code execution goes. When the AI is in the left does it even get to the UpdateAI function?

Comment: Also perhaps try double equals == rather than triple equals === on the IF statements. The triple equals checks types as well as comparing values so will evaluate to false if things aren't exactly matched. And what is the initial value of isHuman on these paddle objects? I see the switch functions which set to the inverse, but are the initial values of this property correctly true or false and not perhaps null?

Comment: my friend helped me fix it, i didn't have var i for all my for loop iterators so it bugged out!

Answer (score 0):

my friend helped me fix it, i didn't have var i for all my for loop iterators so it bugged out!